# Multiple spring messageResources in multiple maven modules?

Tags: spring

I have multiple maven modules that each has it's own message properties file defined in each own's context file.

For example, for module **ABC**, there's the **ABC-context.xml** that define it's own messageSource  like this :

```
<bean id="abcMessageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list id="resources">
            <value>abcMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And for another module, **DEF**, which depends on ABC, has it's own **DEF-context.xml** that defines it's own messageSource like this :

```
<bean id="defMessageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list id="resources">
            <value>defMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I would like the module DEF to somehow be able to merge the abcMessages and defMessages as one messageSource, but am not sure on how to do that.

Please share your ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be something like

```
<bean id="abc_defMessageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list id="resources">
            <value>abcMessages</value>
            <value>defMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But maybe that's too obvious.

Comment: Actually that was where i came from when i was having 1 context file in a single maven module. But when i divide that 1 module into 2 modules, i split the messages also, each module having one messageSource defined in each spring context file. I would like to have 1 'combined' messageSource from all defined messageSources in all context files used for an application. I wonder if im confusing at explaning stuffs :)